# Application against Oracle or Postgres in Weblogic, Sequence Fails

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, oracle11g

I am trying to run the application with the backend Postgres. It worked good,
 But when I changed the Dialect to Oracle application is working good but falling only in sequence, it is trying to run Postgres Query.

**Domain**

```
@Column(name = "person_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "person_seq", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "person_seq", sequenceName = "person_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "title_id")
    private Integer titleId;
    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "forename")
    private String forename;
    @Column(name = "person_name_suffix")
    private String personNameSuffix;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = true)
```

**Error**

```
used by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:884)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1167)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1289)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3593)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3637)
      at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1495)
      at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:135)
      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
      ... 106 more
759 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR uk.gov.justice.cpp.dmu.service.impl.LACourtSessionServiceImpl  - no record found
vax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
      at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
      at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310)
      at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316)
      at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:881)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy221.persist(Unknown Source)
      at uk.gov.justice.cpp.dmu.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl.saveOrUpdate(GenericDAOImpl.java:54)
      at uk.gov.justice.cpp.dmu.dao.impl.GenericDAOImpl.saveOrUpdate(GenericDAOImpl.java:20)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? Without that it would be guessing what is wrong

Comment: I am not sure , why did you put negative point. If you need any info ask for it

Comment: I didn't.  This site has a lot of negative people who just like to vote down without explaining

Comment: That is really bad. When there is a reason give positive points, there should be a reason for negative point

Comment: Can you tell us what method is having problems? Perhaps it may require some additional parameter to perform the task on Oracle that it didn't on Postgres

Comment: It is saveorUpdate method on Hibernate and Weblogic 10.3.6

Comment: Try changing the lazy fetch.  I read in another thread it may have some issues.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond, Thank you for your support. Problem was pretty silly, We are using LiquiBase to setup the data for that we are using Maven which need a dialect, when we are setting the dialect which is hard coded, it is replacing in war  as well. One we fixed that it resolved. This is really silly problem.